# Display variable value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, sum, append

How can I display the `sum` left until free shipping?

The below alerts the `sum` left until free shipping.

```
var sum = 0;
var items = DigitalData[0].Cart.Items;
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
    sum += parseInt(items[i].Price);
    alert(2500 - sum);   
}
```

I try to store the `sum` in a variable named `freeShipping` but get console error?

```
var sum = 0;
var items = DigitalData[0].Cart.Items;
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
    sum += parseInt(items[i].Price);
    var freeShipping = 2500 - sum;    
}
```

I want to display with `.append` the `sum` left until `freeShipping` in text

```
$("span:contains('shoppingcart')").append(" 'sum' left until free shipping");
```

How do I continue?

Comment: Please don't break up your codeblocks with bolded text. If you need to call out a line, put a comment on it, but the above blows the readability completely.

Comment: *"...but get console error?"* ***What*** error? Quote it, in the question, using copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As near as I can tell, you want to get the `sum`, then subtract it from 2500, and show that in a message:

```
// Get the sum
var sum = 0;
var items = DigitalData[0].Cart.Items;
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
    sum += parseInt(items[i].Price);
}

// Subtract it from 2500
var sumUntilFreeShipping = 2500 - sum;

// Display it in a message
$("span:contains('shoppingcart')").append(" " + sumUntilFreeShipping + " left until free shipping");
// Note -------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That's "string concatenation."

---

Side note: Unless you've declared `i` somewhere you haven't shown, that code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Side note 2: Other than Side Note 1 above, your code doing the sum is just fine, but if you like, here's an alternative (it assumes `DigitalData[0].Cart.Items` is an array):

```
var sum = DigitalData[0].Cart.Items.reduce(function(sum, item) {
    return sum + parseInt(item.Price);
}, 0);
```